# Reliable alternative to Timer in .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

Is there relialbe alternative to Timer class in .Net?
We are having issues with System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer, e.g., they start immidietly, or sometimes fire out after long period of inactivity (after 49 days).
I've seen that there seems to be a lot of issues with them like here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/dbc398a9-74c0-422d-89ba-4e9f2499a6a3
We can not use Forms timer.
We are thinking to pause the thread for certain period of time instead of the timer...

Comment: Have you considered using Task Scheduler for activities repeated over long periods? This will work across reboots (eg. Patch Tuesday) unlike framework timers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) describes the difference between the timer classes in the .Net framework.

But maybe another approach can help:

If have have to wait for such a long time it would be better to calculate the `DateTime` when you like something to start. Afterwards your task wakes up every second (or whatever accuracy is needed) and compares the current time with the desired time. If the current time is equal or greater just start your job. Otherwise go to sleep (till the next second, hour, millisecond, whatever). By the way, that's the way how the Microsoft Task Scheduler works.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

> The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the underlying timer mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time. Otherwise, the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure elapsed time. **Use the Frequency and IsHighResolution fields to determine the precision and resolution of the Stopwatch timing implementation.**

Comment: The Stopwatch is for measuring how long something takes, it doesn't start some process after a specified time.

Comment: Agreed, I would suggest to use the Stopwatch with the @Oliver approach (wake up sometimes and check Elapsed time).

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the timer with a new instance every 48 days in the Tick/Elapsed event handler.

The threading will most likely work, but is it going to be worth the extra overhead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also aware of those limitations and have implemented an own timer. Sucked to take that decision, but I have not regretted it so far. As a bonus my own timer implements an interface so that classes using the timer can be unit-tested easily.

Some .NET timers also has a problem where they may invoke the callback before the last callback has finished.

I would recommend putting the timer logic in it's own class rather than pausing a thread.